# Required Number of white balls so that 1 white ball is chosen after x picks

Tags: probability

Lets say that we have a bag of balls (N=100).
We pick 15 balls from the bag (without replacement).

How many white balls (X) should there be in the bag so that we pick at least one white ball with a probability of p>0.5?
How can we calculate this?
What i have done so far is started calculated the probabilities:

First Pick: There is a probability of a1=X/N to find a white ball.

Second Pick: There is a probability of a2=(1-a1)*(X/N-1) to find the ball

Last Pick: There is a probability of a15=(1-a1)(1-a2)*...*(X/N-14)

Then the total probability to find the ball is the sum of all the above, and for the total probability to be >0.5 we just say sum>0.5 and then solve for X.

I am having problems however implementing this in the actual solution.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: @5xum I don't see your close vote.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @5xum OP has done what you've said.

Answer (score 0):

With a bag of 100 balls where you pick 15 balls, to always pick at least one white ball, you need at least 86 balls. This means, at the very worse, you will pick up all the non-white balls and still be able to pick up a white ball.

86 was calculated by N - (N white balls) + 1 = 100 - 15 + 1.

Very likely you'd get many more than 1 white balls, but 86 is the only way to guarantee you'd get at least 1 white ball.

Comment: @baskon1 I answered your question as you wrote it. I am not sure if that is the question you intended to write though given the rather simple solution?

Comment: MBorg, I have changed the question a little bit because obviously it was not very well written (sorry about my English). I don't know if it is allowed to change the question but this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you grab $15$ balls with a shovel. In this way you obtain a random $15$ element subset of $[N]$. There are ${N\choose 15}$ such subsets, all of them equiprobable. If you have bad luck your subset consists only of black balls. There are ${N-X\choose 15}$ such bad subsets. From these facts you can compute the probability that your subset is bad. You want that this probability is $<{1\over2}$. This gives you a condition on $X$.

Unfortunately this condition is not a "simple inequality". You have to use trial and error in order to determine the minimal admissible $X$.

Answer (score 0):

As Christian pointed out, try to find the solution.  Search for the smallest $x$ such that 
$$\frac{\binom{100-x}{15}}{\binom{100}{15}}\leq\frac12.$$
Surprisingly that $x$ equals $5$, so there's no much trial and error.